# Reg: NULL value getting printed

Tags: c

Please find the code below which is showing some weird behavior

```
static int call_apab_process()      
{
   static char *pcFnctnNm = "call_apab_process";
   int rc = SUCCESS;
   char cmd[4000];
   char pid[11];
   char logDir[2000];
   cmd[0] = '\0';
   pid[0] = '\0';
   logDir[0] = '\0';
   dbg_indent(pcFnctnNm);
   dbg_print("Entering Into call_apab_process");
   dbg_print("Print Parameters..");
   dbg_print("MY_HOME     :[%s]",getenv("MY_HOME"));
   dbg_print("SESSION_ID    :[%ld]",pvsp_env->sessionid);
   sprintf(cmd,"%s/bin/GQ19apab_DB_auto.sh %ld",getenv("MY_HOME"),pvsp_env->sessionid);
   sprintf(pid,"0%ld",pvsp_env->sessionid);
   sprintf(logDir,"%s/tmp/db",getenv("MY_HOME"));
   dbg_print("cmd :[%s]",cmd);
}

The output is as given below.

Entering Into call_dadp_process
Print Parameters..
MY_HOME     :[/opt/apnp]
SESSION_ID    :[1054628118]
cmd :[]
```

Can someone please guide me to understand why the value of cmd is displayed as null? When I print the values of MY_HOME and session_id individually I do see that the values are present.

Comment: Change `sprintf` to `snprintf(...., sizeof(...)`. I would guess `sprintf(pid` writes out of bounds.

Comment: You shouldn't allocate big arrays like these on the stack.

Comment: And `"01054628118"` will not fit in 11 bytes because strings are null terminated in C.

Comment: I guess "big" is in the eye of the beholder, @Lundin.  I agree that one should not declare large automatic arrays, but the arrays in the example program don't come anywhere close to the size where I would start to worry.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You haven't programmed a lot of 8-bit microcontrollers, have you  :)

Comment: Not necessarily 8 bit... You can have a super modern ARM or Risc-V with 256K on-board SRAM you want to fit in...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Some 8-bitters have a stack of some 70 to 100 _bytes_. And some extreme low-end ones don't even come with a stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sprintf(pid,"0%ld",pvsp_env->sessionid);
```

definitly writes out of bounds. Your output shows

```
SESSION_ID    :[1054628118]
```

a 10 digit number. In `sprintf()` you add a leading `0` thus you are writing 11 bytes + `'\0'` makes 12 in total, but pid is only defined as `char pid[11];`

That invokes Undefined Behaviour in your case the `'\0'` obviously overwrites the first byte of `cmd` and makes it an empty string (not NULL as you stated what would mean a NULL pointer)

Comment: thank you very much for your response. But could you please explain me a bit more how this would affect a variable which is assigned before this assignment? Sorry i am asking a dumb question.

Comment: @Vimal Kindly elucidate what you mean by *affect a variable which is assigned before this assignment*. There is no assignment in this answer. But I believe you're wondering why it overwrote `cmd`'s first byte? That's because `cmd` happened to be stored next to `pid` in memory, which was a mere happenstance.

Comment: Accepted the Answer :) Thanks a lot to you and all who helped me <3 .